# which method gets control when you do a search and don't specify android:launchMode="singleTop"

Tags: android

I am invoking a standard search, with the Activity that invokes the search being the same as the activity that processes the search (the 'searchable activity').
If I include android:launchMode="singleTop" in the Activity definition, the search invokes the Activity's onNewIntent method and I pick up the search parm specified: no problem.
If you don't specify android:launchMode, or specify a different value for launchMode, 
which method of the Activity gets invokes, or do you always specify android:launchMode="singleTop" in the searchable activity definition in the Manifest file?
Here's what I have specified:

/res/xml/searchable.xml:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same Activity gets started again. So there are two instances of the same Activity in the ActivityStack.

Comment: By that, I'm thinking you mean the onCreate method gets invoked and not the onNewIntent. Do you typically always include android:launchMode="singleTop" in the Activity definition?